# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when I add the -cp parameter in the command line

Tags: java

I have the class **TestSnmp** that is using the default domain.

I copied the class file to a new folder, and when I try to run that class in the command line, I get this error:

```
#java TestSnmp
Error: no se ha podido inicializar la clase principal TestSnmp
Causado por: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/snmp4j/Target
```

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/snmp4j/Target** : That's correct because it needs the **snmp4j-2.5.0.jar**  in the classpath. Now, I copied the JAR file in the same folder, and run the command with the cp parameter I get this error:

```
>java -classpath snmp4j-2.5.0.jar TestSnmp
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal TestSnmp
Causado por: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestSnmp
```

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestSnmp**

What's wrong in the command? I've also tried:

```
#java -cp "snmp4j-2.5.0.jar" TestSnmp

#java -cp .* TestSnmp
```

The directory content:

```
13/02/2019  14:56    <DIR>          .
13/02/2019  14:56    <DIR>          ..
03/05/2016  02:31           480.333 snmp4j-2.5.0.jar
13/02/2019  14:33             4.589 TestSnmp.class
```

Comment: try `java -cp .;snmp4j-2.5.0.jar TestSnmp`

Comment: That worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniele response was right:

```
java -cp .;snmp4j-2.5.0.jar TestSnmp
```

Worked